# How is material-UI made responsive

Tags: material-ui

I discovered this awesome UI framework today and spent significant time going through the docs, I must say, I have fallen in love with it already. Now I want to use it for a medium-scale project, but I have two concerns:

1. I can't find any grid system, how do I go about layout?
2. How do I make it responsive?

I have experience with Zurb's foundation which has a well developed grid system and responsive components. Now you know where I am coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I missed a grid system when I first started using Material-UI but I got used to its way of doing responsiveness. I suspect that since it favors inline styles a grid approach was not ideal. So, here is how you make it respond to the screen size:

```
import React from 'react'

import {Mixins} from 'material-ui'
const {StylePropable, StyleResizable} = Mixins

export default React.createClass({

  // Boilerplate and React lifecycle methods

  propTypes: {
    onChangeMuiTheme: React.PropTypes.func,
  },

  contextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

  mixins: [StylePropable, StyleResizable],

  getInitialState() {
    return {
    }
  },

  // Helpers

  getStyles() {
    let styles = {
      text: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: this.context.muiTheme.rawTheme.palette.primary1Color
      }
    }

    // example of a screen-size sensitive style
    if (this.isDeviceSize(StyleResizable.statics.Sizes.MEDIUM)) {  // active for >= MEDIUM
      styles.text.fontSize = 20
    }

    return styles
  },

  render() {
    let styles = this.getStyles()
    return (
      <p style={styles.text}>Hello world!</p>
    )
  }

})
```